# ERROR a command prompt dialog is open when i execute my script php

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php and i would send an email using script php. I have xampp as server and when I follow tuto's on internet the script doesn't work and in my file error.log I found the error :Connection Closed Gracefully so i search a solution to this problem ,i found this solution :

1. Right click on sendmail.exe
2. Properties
3. Compatibility
4. Change the configuration for all users
5. Execute as Windows XP SP 3
6. Execute as adminitrator

I follow this steps but when I ececute my file which contain

```
<?php mail('destinataire@gmail.com','Sample email','Sample Text','From: xxxxxx@gmail.com'); ?>
```

a dialog  come up to ask me to run the 'send mail' app as admin. I click 'Yes' it will show a command prompt dialog and nothing will happen and my page will hang until the command prompt is closed.Dinally i have the error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\sending\tt.php on line 2

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is you are getting a UAC prompt (asking for permission to run sendmail as administrator), and the time it takes the script to start running, plus the time for you to see and click the UAC prompt is taking over 30 seconds. Your PHP installation is configured to timeout any scripts after they've run for 30 seconds (so they don't just run indefinitely).

At this point, you can extend PHP execution time using [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) (for example, `set_time_limit( 120 );`).

If you would rather disable the prompting all together (not recommended, as you're disabling Windows security measures globally), you can [disable UAC](https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7).

Comment: Instead it seems that the application gets stuck at a certain point... I don't think that in a decent server / pc there is a over 30 seconds delay to show the UAC prompt... so the problem seems that maybe php can't keep on (maybe he disabled error reporting?) so lets the prompt hang on until timeout comes in